# ASM - wrong calculation of visitMaxs - Java 8 type inference

Tags: java-8, java-bytecode-asm

I am using ASM 5.0.3 byte code library with Tomcat 8 and JDK 8. The target application in question is the *Tomcat 8 examples websocket application*. I am getting the `java.lang.VerifyError: Operand stack overflow Exception`.

*(Note that this problem does not manifest with the Tomcat 7 websocket application with JDK 7 and 8.)*

I compared the bytecode prior to injection and bytecode after injection and here are the observations:

- After bytecode injection I expect to see mv.visitMaxs(6,6) for the `broadcast` method of the `websocket/chat/ChatAnnotation` class since I injected one extra local variable which is also kept in the stack.
- Instead, I am seeing mv.visitMaxs(0,6). The difference is shown in the screenshot below:
  [image: comparison of before vs after bytecode injection]

In other words, the `locals` is correct but the `stack` is incorrect.

- The same comparison for Tomcat 7 looks good. The after bytecode output shows the correct mv.visitMaxs(6,6)

As a next step, I compared the source code of `ChatAnnotation.java` for Tomcat 7 vs Tomcat 8. They key difference is the usage of Type Inference for the Java 8 version as is shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Java 7 vs 8 type inference usage]

Once I changed the Java 8 examples source code to remove the type inference (i.e. use explicitly declared type), the problem went away.

**Question:** In ASM, how should I handle  Java 8 type inferences so that I get the correct stackmap?

EDIT#1
Also recompiled the problematic class with Java 1.7 without any code changes, problem goes away. Is ASM 5.0.3 wrongly calculate Max Stack for specific java classes?

Comment: Since ASM doesn't parse source code, the type inference can't be relevant to it. So there is no way to "handle type inference" in ASM as there simply isn't such a thing. Anyway, the responsibility to provide correct arguments to `visitMaxs` is at the *caller* of the method, not ASM.

Comment: Hi Holger, thaks for giving your points. Also observed that, recompilation of the problematic class solves the issue. Seems that ASM handled 'Java 8 type inferences' in the right way.